How To Mark All Emails As Read In A Specific Folder Using Procmail Filter
Currently I have a filter in Procmail to place any emails with the subject WJZGGZ inside of a specific folder called Instantly Warmups.
This is how it looks like in the procmail configuration file:
:0
* ^Subject: .*WJZ4GGZ.*
"$HOME/.Maildir/.Instantly Warmup/"

But how do I add a filter in procmail to automatically mark all the emails inside this specific folder as read?
All emails in other folders should remain unchanged. In other words, if you provide a solution to my problem unread emails in my inbox folder should remain unread.

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

As an aside, the trailing .* is redundant; Procmail's regex looks for a match anywhere in a line so you don't need to say "skip other text" before or after the match.

thank you for the kind note. The * or code in the config file wasn't added manually. It did it through the procmail filter dashboard. I clicked on Mail > Procmail filter in usermin and stated the conditions. After I saved the filter, it automatically placed the trailing *. You dont see it on the frontend. You only witness it when you open the config file so I dont know why it does that. Everytime I add a new filter I have to remember to go back and remove the * in the config file? What happens if I just ignore it?

It's just a minor inefficiency. I'm not familiar with this web admin interface but you might file a bug report for this minor annoyance.

What works entirely depends on how your email client manages message status. Some legacy ones (vaguely IIRC Elm?) store the flags in the message headers, and then you can store the read status there; but other than that, it can't be done - Procmail only gives you access to the actual message at delivery time, not its metadata after delivery.
There may be mechanisms outside of Procmail, and then of course, you could run them from within a Procmail recipe. For example, if you know where a message was delivered, and you have a command to separately mark it as read given its ID, you can run that as an external command from within Procmail.
:0
| msgstore --tell-me-the-uid --message-from-stdin --uid-to-stdout | \
  xargs msgflags --mark-as-read

(These commands don't exist, but you might be able to find commands which perform the described actions for your particular type of mailbox store. The first one delivers a message and tells you where it was delivered, and the second marks the identified message as read.)
For Maildir in particular, the message flags are stored as part of the file name. I'd be hesitant to recommend that you actually do this, but in brief, if you have delivered a message in .Maildir/.Folder/new/deadbeef, you could move it to .Maildir/.Folder/cur/deadbeef:2,S. Perhaps see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir
(This begs the question, why do you even care about the status of these messages? A much better solution would seem to be to ignore this folder so it's not displayed in your regular folder listing if you don't care about the messages there.)

thanks tripleee but I am managing an smtp server for a client and we are using a service called instantly to warmup his domain and IP. If I dont have an option within procmail to mark the messages as read then it causes two big problems:


Client annoyance. Every day he's hitting with 20 or so warmup emails from real people over at Instantly. This can add up very much over time distracting his focus when checking emails.


The more important issue, if we cannot mark emails as read, that means we are not "opening" the emails and reading them.



The purpose of a warmup service is to signal read simulation. If there's no read or mark as read action, the email might get placed in spam due to bad engagement. This defeats the purpose of a warmup service. According to Instantly docs, we need a method of action to :a) automatically read emails; b) mark them as important. Gmail and yahoo has this feature. I cant believe how lackluster procmail is. Some of the basic functions are absent. Why? It's a simple function. I am not code savvy so there has to be a more user friendly to implement this fundamental requirement not luxury.

There is no way that merely automatically flagging the messages as read in the local filesystem could do anything meaningful for the warmup service; nothing in this logic gets transmitted to the sender. I'm guessing their messages have an HTML beacon image which gets fetched when a real user (who hasn't properly secured their email client to prevent this) opens and renders the message. The way to simulate "reading" those messages is to fetch that image.

Having said that, if I'm at all guessing what the service is supposed to do, I'd be vaguely surprised if they didn't ignore "opens" which all came from the same IP address within a split second of sending each message.

Procmail is a tool for automating message delivery. It's an excellent hammer, but your problem is not a nail.

I understand now. I double checked with Instantly and their AI silently reads my emails without opening it on the webmail or usermin. This action alone sends a signal to ISPs like Google and Yahoo that the email has been read. Whether this is true or not who knows, but at least I have a better understanding of how the warm up works now! Thanks for the help!
